# Little Uk standard visitor Visa clarification

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, public-holidays

I'm a student and I intend to visit the UK in my spring's holidays.

Do I have to write on my application form that the time when I'm willing to go on is indeed a public holiday for the whole educational system in my country ? Or even more, prove it with some official paper???

Comment: The people who process your visa application (usually) live in your country and will know when the public holidays are.

Comment: Your *(usually)* made me redo the whole application.

Comment: There are some places where the country is small enough that the visa application is sent to a neighboring country to be processed. But these are pretty uncommon. Normally they are processed at the consulate you applied to, or at least in the main embassy of the country.

Comment: With all due respect, I really became skeptical as hell about them, my country is Algeria and it appears that they dont like us at all even if I'm going with an accommodation to my fully British citizen cousin

Comment: @james smith There’s a section at the end of the application where you can add extra information if you feel it would be helpful to include a comment about travelling during the public holiday period in order not to take time away from your studies.

Comment: Hmm. As far as I can tell they are processed in Algiers from 2014. But it certainly can't hurt to mention the existence of the public holiday, even if they are likely to know it already.